# CircleCI docker image pull policy

Tags: docker, circleci, circleci-2.0

Say we have a simple .circleci/config.yml file:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: account-id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/repo:0.1
```

will circleci always attempt to pull the latest image, or do we need to set an image pull policy of "always"?

something like:

```
  build:
    docker:
      - image: account-id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/org/repo:0.1
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

?

Answer (score 0):

According to [CircleCI support](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015742147-Pinning-a-Docker-image-to-a-specific-version), the version of your docker images might change even between your jobs. Therefore, it is correct to assume that the latest available image will be pulled when your environments are spun up.

If you want to lock down your image to a specific version you can use a checksum sha like so:

```
docker:
  - image: circleci/ruby@sha256:4be65b406f7402b5c4fd5df7173d2fd7ea3fdaa74d9c43b6ebd896197a45c448
```